# Javascript Evaluation Questions

Tags: javascript

```
var  x  =  5;
function f(y){ return (x+y)-2 }; 
function g(h){ var x = 7; return h(x) }; 
{ var x=10; z=g(f) };
```

I'm working through some problems from my textbook in my class to prepare for our next exam, and can't figure out how the above evaluates.

Mostly, I don't understand the call z=g(f), as when f is evaluated, it isn't provided an argument, so how does it evaluate at all? How does it know what y is?

Also, as far as scoping goes, I believe javascript treats most everything as global variables, so the last x that is set would be the x value used in function f, correct?

Thanks for any help!

**Please note, these are extra problems in the back of the book I'm practicing to prepare for the exam, these are not direct homework questions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var  x  =  5;
function f(y){ return (x+y)-2 }; 
function g(h){ var x = 7; return h(x) }; 

{ var x=10; z=g(f) };
```

This sets the global x to 5, then (before any function calls) 10.  The braces don't create a new scope.

You pass `f` into the `g` function (it becomes formal parameter `h`).  That is then called with `x == 7` (`g` is a function with its own scope, so this `x` shadows the global).

Entering `f`, `x` becomes the formal parameter `y`; `y` is thus 7.  `(x + y) - 2` is then `10 + 7 - 2`.

Comment: Because local variable x is `7` in `g`. It doesn't use the global `x`.

Answer (score 2):

I understand why this is confusing.  Let me explain what's going on here, line by line:

```
var  x  =  5;
```

You've probably got this one figured out.  A new variable `x` is declared and assigned the value `5`.

```
function f(y){ return (x+y)-2 };
```

This declares a function that closes around the variable `x` already defined.  It adds this to its argument and subtracts 2, returning that value.

```
function g(h){ var x = 7; return h(x) };
```

This declares a function that declares a local variable `x`, and then calls its argument *as a function* and passes it the value of `x`, which will always be `7`.

```
{ var x=10; z=g(f) };
```

This opens a new code block and declares a variable `x` with a value of 10.  However, since this declaration is in the same scope as the earlier declaration of `x` (blocks do not create new scope in JavaScript!) it will actually assign the value 10 to the existing variable.  Then the block calls the function `g`, passing in the function `f` as its argument.  So, what will happen?  Let's start with the invocation of `g`:

`g` is passed `f`.  Remember that `g` takes a function as a parameter, so this is ok.  `g` will call `f` with the argument `7` and return its value.  So now let's consider `f`.  `f` will be called with `y` being equal to `7`, since that was an argument.  `x` is equal to `10`, since the original `x` var was assigned the value 10.  So it will return `(x+y)-2` or `(10+7)-2`, which is 15.

So `z` will have the value 15 after the script executes.

Answer (score 2):

> Mostly, I don't understand the call z=g(f), as when f is evaluated, it isn't provided an argument, so how does it evaluate at all? How does it know what y is?

Take it step by step.

**Q:** What does function `g` do?
**A:** It takes another function as a parameter and calls that function with the argument `7`.

**Q:** So what does `g(f)` do?
**A:** It calls `f` with the argument `7`, so it's equivalent to `f(7)`.

Notice that writing `f` without parentheses does not actually *call* `f`. In JavaScript functions can be referred to and passed around as arguments just like any other variable. Functions are first class objects, and you can do a lot more with them than merely call them!

**Q:** What is the result of `f(7)`?
**A:** The return statement is `return (x+7)-2`. We need to know the value of `x`.

**Q:** What is the value of `x` inside `f`?
**A:** `x` here refers to the global variable `x`, whose value is `10`. Importantly, the `var x = 7` inside of `g` is a local variable, and is distinct from the global variable. The `var x = 7` declaration from function `g` is irrelevant when we're looking at function `f`.

Also importantly, the statements `var x = 5` and `var x = 10` both refer to the *same* global variable. Local variables are only introduced inside of functions. Simply having naked curly braces and repeating the `var` keyword does *not* introduce a new variable in JavaScript. This is a tricky point, because in other languages like C++ this *would* introduce a new scope and a new variable. In JavaScript it does not. The `var x = 10` could be (and should be!) written as simply `x = 10`.

To be honest, this is a remarkably subtle and confusing point. It makes me wonder if your textbook actually intended to test your knowledge of this idea. It is rather arcane.

**Q:** Okay... so the result of `f(7)` is what?
**A:** It is `(10+7)-2`, or 15.

Comment: This is definitely the best description of what is going on step by step.

Answer (score 0):

- The global variable `x` is set to 5.
- A global function `f` is defined, the first argument passed is aliased as `y`. It returns the result of global x(10) plus y, and then subtracted by two.
- A global function `g` is defined, the first argument passed is alias as `h`. It defines `x` in the function body of `g` **only**. It returns the result of `h` executed with `x` passed as the first argument. `h` is assumed to be a function.
- The expression `{ var x=10; z=g(f) };` is executed in global context and as a result, `x` is redefined from 5 to 10. `z` is assigned the result of `g` invoked and `f` is passed as an argument.

For `z=g(f)`:

- g is invoked. `f` is passed, so in the function body of `g`, `h` becomes `f`. `x` is `7` so now it calls `f(7)` and returns it.
- `f` is invoked and returns `(10+7)-2` which is 15.

The trick is that `{ var x = 10 }` overrides `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript supports higher-order functions, meaning **functions may be passed as arguments into functions, or returned from functions**.  In the call z=g(f), f is not evaluated at all.  The *function* f is passed to g, where it is evaluated (as h).

Javascript does not treat everything as global variables.  Javascript uses static scoping however, meaning that **the global variables used by a function are those in scope where it is defined, not where it is called**.

Comment: "The brackets used in the last line create a region with its own scoping".  No, it doesn't.  Braces alone do not create scopes in JavaScript.